# How should I understand that I need to repartition data pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have many dataframes and many operations between them, including `joins` and `groupby` aggregations.

How can I track at which point I should repartition resulting dataframes to avoid skewness of data?

Should I check for executors utilization in terms of memory and total tasks in Web UI? If so, is there a way to do it programmatically via `pyspark`? I can think of dummy example:

```py
partition_sizes = df.rdd.glom().map(len).collect()
if max(partition_sizes) - min(partition_sizes) > threshold:
     df = df.repartition(N_REPARTITIONS)
```

But it does not seem right, at least since `collect` will trigger the action and if data was skewed then it will already work slower than it should. So how should I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Repartitioning wont fix skew the way you think it will.  When spark does a join it must have all matching keys in the same partition.  It accomplishes this by hashing the equijoin keys and then moduloing them by the number of spark shuffle partitions.  At this point the left and right side of the join have the same number of spark partitions AND all matching join keys are in a deterministic spark partition index.  Now the problem is that if a particular join key has a single value with lots of rows they will necessarily end up in the same spark partition.

Fortunately spark has released a performance feature that under certain circumstances can take a single spark partition and split the computation into several different computation tasks.  You can also do something called a skew join that accomplishes the same thing.

https://docs.databricks.com/en/optimizations/skew-join.html